# Installation of Reactjs on :D\ aborts, but not on :C\ Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

As the title suggest. I am having issues with `npx create-react-app my-app` when trying to initialise a new project on my usb D:\ drive. The problem does not replicate when runnning the same command (and appropriate variations) on the C:\ local drive. Can anyone explain what might be the cause of this issue?

On D:
`npx create-react-app my-app` - begins installation, but is slow. When it reaches `node_modules\@babel\parser` it seems to freeze before aborting the installation with -
`npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Again this only occurs on D:. Installation occurs as normal on C:.
I have tried `npm cache clean --force` and uninstalling/reinstalling nodejs. As well as deleting .npmrc.
Nothing so far explains this issue.

Comment: i think it comes down to permissions. its possible that your npx does not have write permissions on C which is probably the system drive. yarn does have write permissions so you are good to go there. next, please stop creating projects on USB pen drive. they are not reliable. same goes to external drive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing this issue.

BUT

You can try npm instead of npx:

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

Or Yarn:

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I did mention I have tried appropriate variations which did not work. I didn't mention that I had tried yarn however. Interestingly Yarn worked HOWEVER, there was a problem with fetching dependencies and when I tried to import Express it would not work. That said I have found a work around, although the work around is not ideal and doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually answer the "why" of my question but thought I'd post it as an answer incase anyone is running in to the same issue...

Looking deep in to the Error Log I noticed that npx create-react-app wouldn't install on the D:\ drive with a node version >8.10.0. Very strange and again I don't know why this error exists...

I downgraded node using nvm to 8.10.0 and, despite taking a while, this worked. I was then able to go back to using the latest node and install dependencies and npm start with no problem. This is a very strange edge case.